# are filenames visible on encryption

Tags: encryption

I have seen in some posts, that despite encryption, file/path names can be seen (using simple or complex decryption tools).

Can somebody confirm that so far, theres no tool available to view path names for gpg/luks/veracrypt containers/files?

Comment: There are many encryption methods so your answer will vary on details you've not provided. You can also have partial disk encryption (including partition encryption) or full disk encryption meaning parts of the system on disk will be readable without any keys OR none of it, (*within what is required to boot anyway; which will be filenames/locations identical on all boxes as per uEFI/boot standards*) which will vary on details you've not provided.